# Trigger Gives an Error on Multiple Rows SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, trigger

I have a problem when I create a trigger which is giving me this error:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1
>   
> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression***

The Trigger is :

```
Create TRIGGER AccountChange
ON Customer
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    IF(UPDATE(TotalSales))
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @TotalSales MONEY,@AccountNumber NVARCHAR(20),
            @TotalSalesOld MONEY,@customText1 NVARCHAR(50),
            @AccountTypeId int

        SET @TotalSales=(SELECT TotalSales FROM INSERTED)
        SET @TotalSalesOld=(SELECT TotalSales FROM DELETED)
        SET @AccountNumber=(SELECT AccountNumber FROM INSERTED)
        SET @AccountTypeId=(SELECT AccountTypeId FROM INSERTED)


            IF(@TotalSales BETWEEN 0 AND 5000)

                    UPDATE Customer SET AccountTypeID=8 
                      WHERE AccountNumber=@AccountNumber

   END
END
```

Comment: Triggers in SQL Server run once per result set, not once per row in the result set. `INSERTED` will contain all the rows you have updated in the `UPDATE` therefore `TotalSales` could be thousands of different values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your trigger should look like this to handle `UPDATE` with multiple affected rows:

```
CREATE TRIGGER AccountChange
ON dbo.Customer
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE dbo.Customer 
    SET AccountTypeID = 8 
    FROM Inserted i
    INNER JOIN Deleted d ON i.AccountId = d.AccountId  -- use the primary key here
    WHERE AccountNumber = i.AccountNumber
      AND i.TotalSales BETWEEN 0 AND 5000
      AND i.TotalSales <> d.TotalSales  -- TotalSales was updated
      AND dbo.Customer.AccountId = i.AccountId   -- use the PK here
END
```

One single, pretty simple and straightforward set-based statement - and that's all there is!

Answer (score 4):

since `INSERTED` can contain more than one row the update could be performed using a join and not fillin single valued variables:

```
UPDATE C 
SET AccountTypeID = 8 
FROM Customer as C on INSERTED as I on I.AccountNumber = C.AccountNumber
WHERE I.TotalSales between 0 and 5000
```